# GetAssemblyName() fails while ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom() on the same assembly succeeds?

Tags: c#, .net

I ran into many assemblies where AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName() fails while Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom() on the same assembly succeeds. These tend to be NET Core assemblies. One example is

```
 System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
```

On my machine, this assembly with the same FullName has 3 different file versions (FV) and ProcessorArchitecture (PA)

```
 FV=4.6.26515.07   PA=X86     // GetAssemblyName always fails, ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom succeeds when its own PA=X86 
 FV=4.6.27317.03   PA=Amd64   // GetAssemblyName always fails, ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom succeeds when its own PA=MSIL or Amd64 
 FV=4.6.25718.00   PA=Amd64   // GetAssemblyName always succeeds
```

When I run ildasm on all three file versions, all load fine and display proper manifest and CLR Header meaning all of them are CLR assemblies. However, GetAssemblyName() fails on the first two each time. However, ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom() succeeds on the first two as long as you compile the executing assembly with ProcessorArchitecture that matches ProcessorArchitecture of System.Private.CoreLib, i.e. X86 or Amd64. For other types of assemblies, ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom() does not care about their ProcessorArchitecture but for this type it does. Also, why would GetAssemblyName() fail on valid assembly acceptable for ildasm?